# Como acessar um servidor via SSH sem usar senha?

Tags: linux, ssh

Tenho que conectar um servidor Linux via SSH, utilizando o Putty como cliente, muitas vezes ao dia e toda vez eu preciso colocar usuário e senha.
Eu já vi uma pessoa realizando conexão sem utilizar usuário e senha, como isso é possível?

Comment: Achei uma tutorial em inglês de como fazer isso no linux, não sei se realmente pega. [LinuxHorizon](http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/ssh-wo-passw.html) e [Tradução da Página com o Google Tradutor](http://translate.google.com.br/translate?sl=en&tl=pt&js=n&prev=_t&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF-8&u=http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/ssh-wo-passw.html)

Comment: Simples: Insira sua public key no authorized_keys do servidor em questão.

Comment: Como eu não escrevi este post e não se deve colocar uma resposta apenas com o link, dê uma olhada neste endereço: http://www.tonido.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/20/ssh-without-password-using-putty/#.UupbnnddV_g

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O acesso é feito utilizando chaves públicas/privadas.

Primeiramente você precisará gerar a sua chave privada (Se você usa git provavelmente já deve ter uma)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Após gerar a chave públic, envie-a para o servidor

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub USUARIO_REMOTO@SERVIDOR:/home/USUARIO_REMOTO/.ssh/
```

Por fim habilite a chave no servidor.

```
cd ~/.ssh/
cat id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys
chmod 644 authorized_keys
```

Feito isto, a próxima vez que você entrar no servidor `ssh user@host`, não será necessário adicionar a senha.

Comment: Funciona bem para o Linux. Mas a pergunta diz que o cliente está usando o Putty (Windows)

Comment: @Andre no caso do putty, basta usar o comando `pscp` no local do `scp`. Vale lembrar que o diretório do putty deverá estar registrado na variável de ambiente PATH do windows para que estejs disponível no prompt.

Comment: ssh-keygen existe no Windows? Não creio que exista...  A pergunta é sobre Putty (apesar de estar marcada como Linux e ssh) e as respostas também deveriam ser. Coloquei um comentário com um link para um tutorial na pergunta. Acho que vai ajudar um pouco mais quem perguntou do que informações de como fazer isto no Linux.

Comment: @Andre O fato de perguntar conter o putty passou despercebido quando postei a resposta, visto que eu estava vendo a tag [Linux]. Creio que o seu comentário responda corretamente a pergunta.

Comment: "Após gerar a chave privada, envie-a para o servidor" acho que você quer dizer "envie a chave **pública** para o servidor", não? (seu código, pelo menos, está enviando o arquivo `.pub`)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Obrigado, corrigi o erro de digitação.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é comum na AWS, quando vc usa um arquivo .pem para fazer login na máquina. O comando é algo do tipo:

```
# ssh -i ~/.<usuario>.pem <user>@<host>
```

... e vc já está logado.

Dê uma olhada nesse artigo para ver se te ajuda: https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file

Answer (score 1):

Considere que você tem dois servidores: SERVIDOR1 e SERVIDOR2.

No SERVIDOR1, gere a chave RSA:

```
cd
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Resultado esperado para este comando:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/usuario/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/usuario/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/usuario/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/usuario/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
3e:4f:xx:79:xx:9f:96:xx:3b:ad:xx:58:37:bc:37:e4 usuario@S1
```

Forneça as permissões corretas:

```
chmod -v 600 .ssh/id_rsa
```

No SERVIDOR2, crie a pasta ~/ssh dentro do home e crie o arquivo authorized_keys

```
cd 
mkdir ~/.ssh
touch .ssh/authorized_keys
```

No SERVIDOR1, exiba a chave criada.

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Copie e cole o resultado da chave gerada

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAuo0vDDu7vMhc7hum1bgNool+IMfPrt77dZOVAY9fIm1jm8oL57wXXMUe/lcJox+f3YkvGxZMLRUbvM4
```

Volte para o SERVIDOR2, exite o arquivo .ssh/authorized_keys , e cole o conteudo da chave. Em seguida, dê um CHMOD 600.

```
 cd
 nano .ssh/authorized_keys
 chmod -v 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Pronto! Agora já pode fazer SSH do SERVIDOR2 pro SERVIDOR 1 sem precisar digitar a senha.

```
root@servidor:~# ssh 177.10.20.30
The authenticity of host '[servidor1]:64413 ([177.XX.XX.101]:22)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:UbCvey971joqLCsFUc3WBEyTNVEFd2/1Irh6RWMo7xM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[servidor1]:22' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Last login: Mon Jun 20 13:01:19 2016 from 186.242.115.87
```

Você pode ler este artigo completo com mais detalhes: https://www.homehost.com.br/blog/ssh-chave-remota-sem-pedir-senha/