# Ao acessar com usuário especifico ele dar um ssh em outro servidor

Tags: linux, ssh

Tenho 2 Servidores:

Exemplo:A e B.

O que preciso:

quando eu conectar no servidor `A` com um usuário especifico ele automaticamente fazer um `ssh` no servidor `B`, se possível já enviando os parâmetros de login e senha e já logar automaticamente.

Como poderia fazer isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente você tem que configurar o servidor A para que ele possa acessar ao servidor B usando chaves públicas e privadas inves de com usuário e senha. Para fazer isso, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3102/como-acessar-um-servidor-via-ssh-sem-usar-senha?rq=1)

Após isso, pode executar `ssh` para se conectar ao servidor A enviando um outro comando `ssh` para se conectar ao servidor B, por exemplo:

```
ssh root@servidorA "ssh -T servidorB"
```

Comment: Até ai blz, mais como faço para isso ser automático ?, assim eu não quero que meu usuário digite:  ssh root@servidorA "ssh -T servidorB"